# The AlarmManager is unreliable, are there improvements or alternatives?

Tags: java, time, widget, alarmmanager

I need a widget to be updated frequently using a set value, like every 1-5 seconds.
I found out that for this an AlarmManager should be used.
I tested the AlarmManager's setExact() method and found out, that its minimum time is exactly 5 seconds.
I also noticed that the interval can have huge delays.
I tested this with a set interval of 5 seconds.
My test showed for the setExact() method following values: 5s, 5s, 40s, 41s, 19s, 5s, 5s, ...
Using the setRepeating() method showed even worse value: 17s, 39s, 7s, 75s, 60s, ... Apparently the AlarmManager also does not trigger at all when used on a Samsung Device, which is the Device I am planning to use the widget on.
Is there an alternative to using an AlarmManager?
Can the AlarmManager somehow become more reliable?
I need the update rate to be constant, without delays like this.

```
    final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
    (this, NOTIFICATION_ID, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            + 3000;
    long repeatInterval = 1000;
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            triggerTime, notifyPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the AlarmManager I have checked out the JobScheduler and Worker, but both seem to underlie a 15 minute (!) minimum interval.
Using a simple Thread seems to be working however. I just have to find out how to make it run reliably then...
If you know other solutions please let me know!